# MySQL/PHP: Auto-Suggest entries similar to this one

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a website which allows the user to read/write/save/edit/... texts (so calles posts) online. Well, everything works fine but now I'd actually need a bit of help.

YouTube for instance suggests a list of videos which might also be interesting for me. This suggestion is also based on which video I'm currently watching. If I watch a video about "Driving a Ferrari", the next suggestion could be "Driving a Lamborghini"... Now I also want to implement something like that on my Website. It really does not need to be that accurate, I am just looking for a simple and efficient way to implement a "this could also be interesting for you"-area.

I have absolutely no idea about how to start and would be thankful for every single idea!

Comment: remember not to ask a general questions

Comment: any feed back about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [PredictionIO](https://prediction.io/) server. However if you need only mysql/php solution there are couple of ways:

- Using MySQL's [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Query would look like something as:

  ```
  SELECT id, body, MATCH (title, body) AGAINST
    ($title IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
  FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST
    ($title IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
  ```

However mysql's fulltext search is awful. Better to look into [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), or [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/), or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/)

- Using simple LIKE to match title to other posts:

  ```
  $title = "Video about my awesome cat - Michael";
  $parts = preg_split("/[\s,\-]+/", $title);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE ";
  $where = [];
  $binds = [];
  foreach ($parts as $part) {
      $where[] = "(title like ?)";
      $binds[] = "%" . $part . "%";
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ok this is a very basic and simple way..suppose the item that user is watching now  have a title in its database row.so..suppose the title is "Driving a Lamborghini"..i take the title,explode it into an array by using

```
$titlearray = explode(' ',"Driving a Lamborghini");
```

now i have an array that can be used to  make a simple search select query for similars:

```
$select = "SELECT * From TABLE_NAME WHERE ";
foreach($titlearray as $key=>$title){
  $titlearray[$key]="LIKE '%".$title."%'";
}
$select .="(" . implode(' OR ',$titlearray) .")";
```

now you have simple select query to get similarities to that title. you can put an order and limit too.

Comment: I would filter out every word with length smaller than 4, so you don't get every result containing 'a', 'at', 'and', 'by' and so on. Or define an filter array with those words.